# Gimmicky touchpad

Tags: touchpad

My laptop = MSI GS65 Stealth Thin 8rf
OS - Ubuntu 18.04

When I wake my laptop from suspend, sometimes(and not always), the touchpad stops working.

While I am typing, my palm often hits my touchpad and moves the cursor(often selecting large blocks of text which get deleted when I hit the next key) - Does not happen on Windows. I think there might be a sensitivity problem or a typing threshold.

Answer (score 0):

The external monitor going dark for a second sounds like a pretty natural behavior of a laptop having multiple displays honestly. In terms of the touch pad, I can't be entirely sure what the issue is, but I did find the official Ubuntu Documentation on the Synaptics Touchpad: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad

Here's a line from that article that should help you get started too:

Ubuntu provides basic configuration of your touchpad options in System > Preferences > Mouse, under the Touchpad tab.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you also use a mouse...

Install `Touchpad Indicator` GNOME extension. Perfect.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/131/touchpad-indicator/

Switch the touchpad, trackpoint, fingertouch, touchscreen or a pen device on and off easily from the top panel. Optionally, automatically disable some or all devices when a mouse is plugged in and re-enable them when unplugged.

Comment: Not what I am looking for. I am looking for both my mouse and touchpad to work, but my touchpad to not detect my palm while I am typing.